# What is the correct architecture when upgrading multiple small vb6 applications to a centralized MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, vb6

## Challenge:

We currently have 100+ vb6 applications. Our setup is that for every desktop server that we have (currently 20), those apps should be installed. So all in all, you can do the math. Users would then approach that server, or connect through RDC, and they will generate their reports there. Problems have already popped up, but the main reason the management now chose to upgrade is because we do not have VB6 dev't licenses anymore.

## What we are currently using:

- Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Professional
- Microsoft Server 2008 R2 (For the deployment)
- Oracle 11g (where the data are coming from)

## The Question:

Given the cards we were dealt, I would like to seek a proper strategy in consolidating these decentralized reports. Right now, I'm suggesting we do MVC. However, I am not certain how it should be done in such a way that multiple developers can contribute in the development simultaneously. How/what will be the layers (DAL/BLL)?

We are new to this coming from a VB6 background. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, not to rain on your parade, but questions like this always boil down to ROI (return on investment), and based on what you've said, your ROI is incredibly small. MVC is a good bet, since it's based on a pattern that all good applications should follow to a greater or lesser extent, *but* if you're stuck with VS2010, you won't be able to work with the latest and greatest versions of MVC/Web API/Entity Framework/etc. That means your brand spanking new app will already be out of date and rotting before you even kick it out the door.

If your organization is unwilling or unable to upgrade to at least VS2012 (but as long as you're doing that you might as well go all the way to 2013), so that you can utilize MVC5, Web API 2, and Entity Framework 6, then forego any new development and just do the bare minimum to make your current applications work. From a cost perspective it's just insane to go into new development on old, out-dated technology.

Comment: Ok I get your point. It's just sad that we can't jump to VS2012 because it would be a long process and a lot of signatures from the higher-ups. With this at hand, and with our VB6 licenses already expired, is there any suggestion on how we could go about this? In other words, like a "work-around"?

Comment: I would maybe just go Web forms for now as it will be less of a jump and you can still use VB. You technically can with MVC as well,  but C# is far more common there making a VB MVC app sort of weird.

Comment: Ok I'll keep this in mind. But, moving forward, if ever I can convince/push them to do the necessary stuff and jump to VS2012/13 and leverage the new MVC and EF, regardless of our inexperience in C#, what/how should we do?